# Navigating from one List to another in SplitApp in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to make Shopping Cat App in `SAPUI5`. It is in the demo kit of `SAPUI5.hanaondemand.com`.

I want to move from one List1 to another by clicking on an Item of a list1. My code is as follows-

```
itemPress:function(oControlEvent)
{                                                     
   sap.m.MessageToast.show("Inside Function");

   var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId('idShoppingCart');// ID of the age where my list 1 is

   app.to("idMasterpage1");// id of the page where i want to move    
}
```

Please tell me the error in this code...

Answer (score 0):

I believe much more detail is needed. Can you post an SSCCE? http://sscce.org/

Also - please include the error from your relevant browser console so that it is clear what the possible problems might be.

Thanks.

Comment: NO error is coming and i have added breakpoint also. Then i got to know that control is not going into my function.

Comment: Unfortunately, without knowing what your "idShoppingCart" identifies, what "idMasterpage1" refers to, etc. it will be quite difficult to provide any accurate answers. I still urge you to write a more detailed example of your view and controller. I would suggest that the "itemPress" event is not firing since you may not have set the mode of your List in the master page correctly. But again this is a guess.

Comment: Also make sure all pages are added to the App control before attempting to navigate. That might be another issue.